# rsyslog config with both "$msg contains" and "$fromhost-ip startswith"

Tags: config, rsyslog

can i use the statement both "$msg contains" and "$fromhost-ip startswith" in rsyslog config?

when i use the follow for rsyslog config, it work!

```
if $msg contains 'src_port=6699' then -?DynFileA
& ~
if $fromhost-ip startswith '10.10.10.1' then -?DynFileB
& ~
```

but when i combine both of them, it was fail!

```
if $fromhost-ip startswith '10.10.10.1' and $msg !contains 'src_port=6699' then -?DynFileA
& ~
```

i search many article from internet, especially rsyslog office document,but didn't find any useful suggestion!

can any one tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... are you sure about your substitution ? At first sight, if your host IP is 10.10.10.1, you'll apply -?DynFileA instead of -?DynFileB. And your first example held two distincts operations... (don't know what it is btw)

regards,

Answer (score 0):

I would just go full rsyslog Reiner script now,  your first example was a **or**, not an **and** with two different dynamic file templates, if that is what you wanted just replace the **and** below with an **or**

```
if ($fromhost-ip startswith '10.10.10.1') and ($msg !contains 'src_port=6699') then {
    -?DynFileA
    stop
    }
```